# RegEx: nested tags

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-replace, nested-loops

I use regexp, but I cant do it for my case. I have create own engine like DLE. 
I have tags like [a],[/a],[b],[/b] etc. I use regexp like

```
'\\[a\\](.*?)\\[/a\\]'si
```

or like

```
'\\[a\\](.*?)(\\[/a\\])+'si
```

and it don't work how I want.
I need receive:

```
from '[a]delete[/a]' : ''

from '[a][b]delete[/b][/a]' : '',

from '[a][a]delete[/a][/a]' : '', with '\\[a\\](.*?)\\[/a\\]'si it returns '[/a]'

from '[b][a]delete[/a][b]' : '[b][/b]'

from '[b][a]delete[/a][b] [a]delete[/a]' : '[b][/b]'

from '[a]
          delete
          [a]
              [b]delete[/b]
          [/a]
          delete
      [/a]
      [b]
          [a]delete[/a]
          nodelete
      [/b]'
      :
      '[b]
          nodelete
      [/b]'
```

Help me to create right regexp!

Comment: That syntax seems close to HTML. And be aware that [HTML can't be parsed with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630). Maybe that applies to your syntax too.

Comment: What is your input? Or is the information in your post your input? If so, what is your expected output?
As @Oriol points out, you can't parse HTML (and similar structures) with RegEx, you probably want a recursive function that might make use of RegEx

Comment: I can to write own function for my task. But I want to know: can I user regex in this task?

Comment: template for my post is: "'input' : 'output'"

Comment: The output seems to be the tags with syntax errors. Why "nodelete" is the output of the last one?

Comment: I edit. New output is correct.

Comment: [PHP has a built-in BBCode functions.](http://php.net/book.bbcode)

Comment: @Gumbo: This is not "built-in" at all, this is a pecl extension *(last release August 2008, and it's the hell to compile it)*. However, it will be very handy to do it in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP way**

You can do it in one pass with php. But to deal with nested tags, you need to use the recursion feature, so you can't do the same with Javascript:

```
$text = preg_replace('~\s*\[a](?:[^[]+|\[(?!/?a])|(?R))*+\[/a]\s*~', '', $text);
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kH3hN3/1)

**pattern details**

```
~                  # pattern delimiter
\s*                # only here to remove leading whitespaces
\[a]
(?:                # non-capturing group: describes the allowed 
                   # content between tags:
    [^[]+          #    - all that is not a [
  |                #  OR
    \[ (?!/?a])    #    - a [ that is not the begining of an opening
                   #       or closing "a" tag
  |                #  OR
    (?R)           #    - recurse to the whole pattern
)*+                # repeat the group zero or more times (possessive quantifier)
\[/a]
\s*                # to remove trailing spaces
~
```

**Javascript way**

Since the recursion feature is not available for the ECMAScript regex engine, a way to solve the problem is to use several pass of replacements that targets the innermost "a" tags. To accomplish this task you can use this pattern that forbids nested "a" tags *(note that the pattern is very similar to the previous, the syntax `(?=(subpattern*))\1` only emulates a possessive quantifier)*:

```
text = text.replace(/\s*\[a\](?=((?:[^\[]+|\[(?!\/?a\]))*))\1\[\/a\]\s*/g, '');
```

You need to apply this replacement until there is no more tags to replace. You can detect the number of replacements using a closure as replacement that increments a counter, then you put all in a `do...while` loop. Example:

```
var counter;    
do {
    counter = 0;
    text = text.replace(/\s*\[a\](?=((?:[^\[]+|\[(?!\/?a\]))*))\1\[\/a\]\s*/g, function (m) {counter++; return '';});
} while (counter>0)
```